# Pretrained word 2 vec models for social media

Tags: word2vec

I have tried using en_core_web_lg, the results have been pretty good but I was wondering if there are any better pre-trained word 2 vec models that might be better to vectorize a dataset of social media data (tweets)?

I have also trained my own word 2 vec model on the dataset using gensim, the results are slightly worse than en_core_web_lg.

My dataset is not large.
Any suggestions would help thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hugging Face hub has many pretrained models. One example is [fse/glove-twitter-100](https://huggingface.co/fse/glove-twitter-100) which are pretrained glove vectors based on 2B tweets.